# Difficulty with zoom and free monads

Tags: haskell, state-monad, haskell-lens, free-monad

I am mucking around with free monads and lens, using the free monad to create my own version of the IO monad:

```
data MyIO next
    = LogMsg String next
    | GetInput (String -> next)
    deriving (Functor)
```

I am stacking this on top of a state monad like so: `FreeT MyIO (State GameState) a` where `GameState` is:

```
data GameState = GameState { _players :: [PlayerState] }
```

Now, what I would like to have is a way to "zoom-into" a `PlayerState` from a `GameState` context. Something like this:

```
zoomPlayer :: Int -> FreeT MyIO (State PlayerState) a -> FreeT MyIO (State GameState) a
zoomPlayer i prog = hoistFreeT (zoom (players . element i)) prog
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
No instance for (Data.Monoid.Monoid a1)
  arising from a use of ‘_head’
```

This error seems related to the fact that `players . element i` is a traversal; if I remove the list aspect from `_players` and use normal lens then the code works.

Any ideas on how to write this function?

Comment: Would it not be easier to instead have `StateT GameState (Free MyIO) a`?  If you are wanting to later swap `Free MyIO` for `IO` then this would be the usual way, since there is no transformer version of `IO`.

Comment: Also, the problem stems from the fact that indexing a list is not a safe operation.  The lens library wants you to return a type that can be defaulted, and the standard typeclass for this is `Monoid`.  If you simply add `Monoid a => ` to the type signature of `zoomPlayer` then you'll be set.  This does restrict what you can return, of course, but you'll have to unless you want to write more code.

Comment: @bheklir My bad, the `a`in the error was a typo; it was actually `a1`. I'm sorry for the confusion. It seems like `FreeF` is the thing it expects to be a monoid, but I don't have a way of writing an instance for that. Maybe I could temporarily wrap it in a list and then unwrap it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure you'll never index into a non-existing player and don't mind a little unsafety, you can use the [`unsafeSingular`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.9/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:unsafeSingular) combinator to turn a `Traversal` into a `Lens`, like this:

```
zoomPlayer :: Int -> FreeT MyIO (State PlayerState) a -> FreeT MyIO (State GameState) a
zoomPlayer i prog = hoistFreeT (zoom (players . unsafeSingular (element i))) prog
```

(Also, perhaps I would use [`ix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.9/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#v:ix) instead of `element`, but that's unrelated to the problem.)

We can also construct safe indexing lenses for always-infinite sequences, like streams defined using [`Cofree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.11/docs/Control-Comonad-Cofree.html) from the `free` package:

```
import Control.Lens (Lens', _Wrapped')
import Control.Comonad.Cofree (Cofree, telescoped)
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Control

sureIx :: Int -> Lens' (Cofree Identity a) a
sureIx i = telescoped $ replicate i _Wrapped'
```

But a game is unlikely to have infinite players.